# Storing a particular ERC20 balance value of a smart contract in a global or local variable

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

how does one go about storing the ERC20 balance value of a contract in a local variable, with the ultimate purpose of using this value for later calculations within the same function?

```
uint256 varName = ERC20Object.balanceOf(this);
```

if done locally within a function it will always return 0 regardless of the ERC20Object balance being e.g. 1k-100mil. **How to fix this and have varName show the correct number instead of 0?**

Comment: I think you will need to share a bit more code, like you how instantiated the ERC20Object. I suggest you quickly mock up a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you expect to work, and we can then assist.

Comment: I'm stuck in this function: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55911/solidity-math-whats-wrong-with-the-function/55925?noredirect=1#comment66422_55925 due to the concern of this question.